# Django - Signals multiple values for keyword argument 'sender'

Tags: django

```
def pre_save(self, model_instance, add):
        value = super(MediaUploadField, self).pre_save(model_instance, add)
        if value and add:
            post_save.connect(self.someCallback, sender=model_instance.__class__, dispatch_uid='media_attachment_signal')
        return value

    def someCallback(sender, **kwargs):
        print "callback"
        print sender
        return
```

Is throwing the following error:

```
someCallback() got multiple values for keyword argument 'sender'
```

I honestly can't work out what I'm doing wrong, I followed the documentation precisely. I tried replacing model_instance.**class** with the actual class import but it throws the same error.

Does any have any idea whats wrong with my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that `someCallback` is a model method. The first argument to model methods is always the instance itself - which is usually referenced as `self`. But you've called the first argument `sender` - so Python is trying to receive `sender` both as the first positional argument, and as one of the keyword arguments.

The best way to solve this is to define `someCallback` as a staticmethod, as these don't take the instance or class:

```
@staticmethod
def someCallback(sender, **kwargs):
```

Also note that connecting your post_save handler in a pre_save method is a very strange thing to do. Don't forget that connecting a signal is a permanent thing - it's not something that's done on a per-call basis.

Comment: Yea, I know it's a very strange thing to be doing. I'm trying to create an 'attachment' when the user adds some media to an object, but obviously I can't do that until the model is saved. Since I want to keep the app which creates the attachment independent, I can't use my other models save method or attach the signal that way. Thanks though, I feel stupid for not noticing this.